# Its sure its simple but i cant make my fading div stop on mouseover

Tags: mouseover, fade, out

ok im really a beginner when it comes to this but im trying to get this JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout(function(){
$("div.left-col-wrap-outer").fadeOut("slow", function () {
$("div.left-col-wrap-outer").remove();
  });

}, 9000);


});
```

to stop the animation/fade out after 9 seconds with a mouseover then to restart the 9 sec timer on mouseoff.

Any help really appeciated

Comment: can you please explain in a clear way

Comment: when i move my mouse over the div 'left-col-wrap-outer' which is currently set with the above fade out after 9 seconds. i want to be able to stop the fade out until i move my mouse off this div

Comment: Anyone??. The following page www.dgimages.co.nz the box under the DGIMAGES logo will disappear after 9seconds. I want it to stay IF the users mouse is hovering over it and disappear after 9 seconds when the users mouse leaves it again. ??

Comment: Please be patient. We are a community, not people who get paid to solve these problems all day (though that would be nice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
   $("div.left-col-wrap-outer").mouseleave(function(e){
       $("div.left-col-wrap-outer").fadeOut("slow");
});
});
```

do you want this?

Comment: thats working perfectly except i still require the 9 second disappear if the mouse is removed from the div or if it never enters the div

Comment: you want that the fadeOut time should be of 9 seconds?

Comment: i think i got it too work for the time being thanks to both of you, my code is very messy :-/ but it works just without a delay of 9 seconds after moving the mouse off the div. Thanks

Comment: i would like to refine the code as you want.. if you can be little clear about your requirement.. do you want to fadeOut the div after 9 seconds when you remove your mouse from div??

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var fade = setTimeout(function(){
        $("div.left-col-wrap-outer").fadeOut("slow", function () {
                $("div.left-col-wrap-outer").remove();
        });
    }, 9000);
    $("div.left-col-wrap-outer").mouseout(function() {
        fade = setTimeout(function(){
            $("div.left-col-wrap-outer").fadeOut("slow", function () {
                    $("div.left-col-wrap-outer").remove();
            });
        }, 9000);
    });

    $("div.left-col-wrap-outer").mouseover(function() {
        clearTimeout(fade);
    });
});
```

Comment: thats kind of working but it seems to be starting the timer and fade out animation on the mouseover rather than the other way round. I need; no mouseover at all = div fades out after 9 seconds. mouseover div = div stays visible until mouse leaves. mouse leaves div = div fades out after 9 seconds

Comment: Fixed. Just add another `setTimout` outside of the mouseout function.

Comment: mmm still dosent seem to be working, in fact its doing exactly the same as my original code..

Comment: It doesn't help that I'm on a mobile device at the moment. So how about this updated code.

Comment: Hopefully we get it on this third time around. :)

Comment: i think i got it too work for the time being thanks to both of you, my code is very messy :-/ but it works just without a delay of 9 seconds after moving the mouse off the div. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Q. SHeets i can only vote one answer up but i used a bit of both, cheers again and thanks for your time